# GET 405 method not allowed

Tags: c#, jquery, json, web-services, asp.net-web-api

This is my jquery code to call web api

```
var request = {
    RequestId: "123",
    DeviceId: "ACU-B2-01-R1",
    AccessType: "Unlock",
    LoginId: "tester",
    Password: "tester"
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:55208/api/accesspanel',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(request),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
    }
});
```

When I run this code, nothing happens. Neither the success nor error block gets fired. After checking in the debug console of chrome, this is the error record:

```
GET http://localhost:55208/api/accesspanel?callback=jQuery18203847100134007633_…22,%22LoginId%22:%22tester%22,%22Password%22:%22tester%22}&_=1364916423737 405 (Method Not Allowed) 
    send jquery.min.js:2
    p.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:2
    (anonymous function)
```

I am, however, able to call my web api method successfully using C# code, which looks like this:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55208/");

        var request = new DeviceAccessRequest
        {
            RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            DeviceId = "ACU/B2/01/R1",
            AccessType ="Unlock",
            LoginId = "tester",
            Password = "tester" ,                    
        };
        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/accesspanel", request).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var deviceAccessResponse = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DeviceAccessResponse>().Result;

        }
    }
```

And this is my web api method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostDeviceControl(DeviceAccessRequest deviceAccessRequest)
    {

        var deviceAccessResponse = new DeviceAccessResponse(deviceAccessRequest.RequestId)
            {
                Status = "OK"
            };
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<DeviceAccessResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, deviceAccessResponse);
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing a GET request in your console is because you specified `dataType: 'jsonp'` which works only with GET requests (the reason for that is because jQuery translates this to a `<script>` tag pointing to the url you specified). If you want to be doing cross domain AJAX with other verbs than GET you cannot use JSONP. If you need to use other verbs (such as POST in your case) you have 2 options:

- [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Take a look at the [`following video`](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/ASPNET-Web-API-and-CORS-Support) which illustrates how you could enable CORS on your Web API. Obviously for this to work your client side browser need tio support it
- Server side bridge on your domain. The idea here is to have some server side script on the domain hosting your javascript code that will send the HTTP request to the API and return the response to the client. Then you will send a regular AJAX POST request to your own domain